# Changing self class from inside a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's start off with the assumption I want a method that allows an
object to transform itself into another object. Where B is a A object

(In B model) -->

```
def change_type
  self = self.becomes (A)
end
```

But anyway I can't can't change "self". How can I fix it? The cast must be in model.

Comment: That is impossible.

Comment: This smells of bad OOP to me. Why would you need to do that? `B` __is__ an `A` already.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way. You can't overwrite `self`. Or any object<sup>*</sup>, as a matter of fact.

---

<sup>* You can reassign reference/variable, but not the object itself.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the class of an object once created, nor can you change an object into another object.

You are thinking of [Smalltalk's `become:` method](https://gbracha.blogspot.de/2009/07/miracle-of-become.html), which can make one object become another object (and thus as a special case also change an object's class). Ruby doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0):

If class `B` inherits class `A`, then an instance of `B` is born an instance of `A`. No need to change.

```
class A; end

class B < A; end

b = B.new

b.is_a?(A)  #=> true
```